# Error constantly shown in terminal after installing ESET NOD32 for Linux 64bit

Tags: linux-mint, shared-library

This error message is constantly shown in terminal after installing ESET NOD32 version 4.0.82.0 for Linux 64bit on Linux Mint 18:

> ```
> ERROR: ld.so: object 'libesets_pac.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded: ignored.
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit this file with your favorite text editor as root:

```
/etc/ld.so.preload
```

Safe example, through `sudoedit`:

```
sudoedit /etc/ld.so.preload
```

If it contains:

```
libesets_pac.so
```

Change the content to:

```
/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so
```

Save the file and the library will be preloaded for new processes.

You should restart the system to make it active for all processes.

Comment: Did it and nown I have: "ERROR: ld.so: object '/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored."

Answer (score 0):

If the answer by @LinuxSecurityFreak does not work, just remove the entry from `/etc/ld.so.preload`
and in `/etc/rc.local` add

```
/opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_daemon
```